# how can I format the following laravel collection

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-collection

Thanks in advance! I have the following collection in Laravel.

```
$data = collect([
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'filter' => 'brand',
        'value' => 'apple'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'filter' => 'color',
        'value' => 'red'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 3,
        'filter' => 'color',
        'value' => 'blue'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 3,
        'filter' => 'storage',
        'value' => '8GB'
    ]
]);
```

I need it exactly like this:

```
[
    "brand" => ["apple"],
    "color" => ["red", "blue"],
    "storage" => ["8GB"]
]
```

How can I format this like above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
$grouped = $collection->mapToGroups(function ($item, $key) {
    return [$item['filter'] => $item['value']];
});

$grouped->toArray();
```

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/need-help-with-formatting-laravel-collection#reply=486863